# tabulator performance issue when using on html tabs

Tags: tabulator

i have created a webpage which has a tab control with two tabs. Each tab has a tabulator table on it. As i switch between the tabs i noticed a significant lag. By the 5th tab click, the entire webpage is hung up.

Using tabulator 5
Virtual DOM
no dataset (ie empty table being rendered)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you include a working demo

Comment: I created a CodePen with Tabulator 5 and Bootstrap 5 tabs a while ago. I don't notice any slowdown issues. You can have a look here 
https://codepen.io/shunty/pen/QWQpKrp
And/or give us a sample to work with.